# MongoDB - findOne(query) vs countDocuments(query, {limit: 1})

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using Node.js and its native MongoDB Driver. I am not sure which of the two methods is efficient to check if at at least one record matches my query criteria. **Please note, I don't need any fields of that record if existing.**

```js
const query = {
  status: 'running',
  'data.srId': 'certainValue'
};
```

`data.srId` is indexed.

`collection.findOne(query, {id: 1})` vs `collection.countDocuments(query, {limit: 1})`

Which of the two would be better for my usecase? If there is anything better than these two, please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: Are `data.srId` values unique?

Comment: @jQueeny, 90% of the time they are unique but not always.

Comment: The `findOne` is just a wrapper for `find(query).limit(1)`. With an index on `data.srId` the `executionTimeMillis` and `executionTimeMillisEstimate` on 1 million documents for me with your query was `0`. If `data.srId` were unique you wouldn't need the `limit(1)`. The index is already optimising your query. Using `find(query).limit(1)` will be almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`countDocuments()` would generally be more efficient.

For more details use `.explain()` function to compare `executionStats` & `executionTimeMillis`.

```js
const explanation = await collection.countDocuments(query, { limit: 1 }).explain();
console.log(explanation);
```

---

You might use aggregate function.

```js
const pipeline = [
    { $match: { 
        status: 'running',
        'data.srId': 'certainValue'
    }},
    { $limit: 1 }
];

const aggregationResult = await collection.aggregate(pipeline).toArray();

if (aggregationResult.length > 0) {
    console.log('At least one record matching the query.');
} else {
   console.log('No records matching the query.');
}
```

Comment: Now, that I see the documentation, countDocuments() wraps the following aggregation operation and returns just the value of `n`:

`db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: <query> },
   { $group: { _id: null, n: { $sum: 1 } } }
])`